# Inline text change not updating on ajax request (but changes on DB)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a script I found for changing a line of text on the go (you click on it and an input shows). It works fine without doing anything to the database but when I add my code for an update, it will update the DB but won't refresh the text after it submits. I'm totally lost now since I've been at it for hours, maybe I'm missing something very basic.

My JS:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: '/ajax/nombreruta.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    timeout: 500
});



$('.editable').inlineEdit({
    value: $.ajax({ data: { 'action': 'get' } }).responseText,
    buttons: '',
    cancelOnBlur: true,
    save: function(event, data) {
        var html = $.ajax({
            data: { 'action': 'save', 'value': data.value }
        }).responseText;

        //alert("id: " + this.id );

        return html === 'OK' ? true : false;
    }
});
```

nombreruta.php:

```
<?php session_start();

$action = isset($_POST) && $_POST['action'] ? $_POST['action'] : 'get';
$value  = isset($_POST) && $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] : '';

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/util-funciones.php";//for my db functions

$cnx=conectar();
$sel="select * from ruta where id_ruta='".$_SESSION['ruta']."'";

$field=mysql_query($sel, $cnx);
if($row=mysql_fetch_object($field)){
$data = $row->nombre;
}

switch ($action) {

// retrieve data
case 'get':
    echo $data;
    break;

// save data
case 'save':
    if ($value != '') {


        $sel="update ruta set nombre='".$value."' where id_ruta=".$_SESSION['ruta'];
        mysql_query($sel,$cnx) or die(mysql_error());

        $_SESSION['data'] = $value;

        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: no se han recibido valores.";
    }
    break;

// no action
default:
    echo "ERROR: no se ha especificado accion.";
    break;
}
```

Firebug shows me that after I update my text it returns OK and after I refresh the site it will show the updated text but not before. I started thinking this approach is too much hassle but after so much hours I feel like I'm one step from my solution...

EDIT:

I'm using this plugin: http://yelotofu.com/2009/08/jquery-inline-edit-tutorial/

And my html is just

```
 <span class="editable">Text</span>
```

Comment: Please also include your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me....

Here's the demo app I put together (asp.net, but basically the same minus the database).

Just to be clear: Press Enter to save. Click off to cancel (since you removed the buttons).

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/caphun/jquery.inlineedit/master/jquery.inlineedit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                url: 'Test.ashx?' + window.location.search.substring(1),
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                timeout: 500
            });

            $('.editable').inlineEdit({
                value: $.ajax({ data: { 'action': 'get'} }).responseText,
                buttons: '',
                cancelOnBlur: true,
                save: function (event, data) {
                    var html = $.ajax({
                        data: { 'action': 'save', 'value': data.value }
                    }).responseText;
                    return html === 'OK' ? true : false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="editable">Test 1</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //Custom Object to Get and Format my Connection String from the URL
    QueryStringObjects QSO = new QueryStringObjects(context.Request, "InlineAjaxTest");

    //Look for any GET or POST params named 'action'
    switch (context.Request.Params["action"])
    {
        //If 'action' = 'save' then....
        case "save":
            //Open a connection to my database (This is a custom Database object)
            using (DataBrokerSql SQL = GetDataBroker(QSO.Connstring))
            {
                //Create a SQL parameter for the value of the text box
                DbParameter[] Params = {
                    new SqlParameter("@val", context.Request.Params["value"])
                };
                //Execute an Insert or Update
                SQL.ExecSQL(@"UPDATE
                                    Test_InlineAJAX
                                SET
                                    Value = @val
                                IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
                                    INSERT INTO
                                    Test_InlineAJAX
                                    VALUES
                                    (@val)", Params);

            }
            //Return OK to the browser
            context.Response.Write("OK");
            break;
        default:
            //Open a connection to my database
            using (DataBrokerSql SQL = GetDataBroker(QSO.Connstring))
            {
                //Get Value from my table (there's only one row so no need to filter)
                object obj = SQL.GetScalar("Select Value From Test_InlineAJAX");
                //If my value is null return "" if not return the value of the object
                context.Response.Write(obj != null ? obj.ToString() : "");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_InlineAJAX](
    [Value] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Not sure what else to tell you, but maybe something here will give you an idea...

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see where I might be making my mistake in my code :S This is the first time I see asp too. It worked for me without the database connection too, I need to see what the issue is when I start updating the db after I change the text.

Comment: I modified my code to save to the database (I also added in some explanations for the C# code), but it still works fine. I don't read PHP very well but there doesn't seem to be any major things that look like they'd be causing your error. Perhaps make sure that your jQuery version is the latest...? Other than this I think I'm out of ideas. Sorry I couldn't be a better help. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you anyway, I'll have a look at it to see what I can understand.